Simple DHCP Server for Assigning IP Addresses and Providing Internet Access on Windows
I'm looking for a simple, straightforward solution to set up a DHCP server on a Windows system that can:

Dynamically assign IP addresses to connected clients.
Provide internet access to these clients through a shared connection.

I've tried tftpd64, but I'm having trouble connecting to clients via the internet as mentioned with this current post.

Turns out that Windows provides a DHCP server from a windows service called Internet Connection Sharing (ICS). As mentioned by the Wikipedia page:

The computer that shares its Internet connection serves as a gateway device, meaning that all traffic between other computers and the Internet go through this computer. ICS provides Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) and network address translation (NAT) services for the LAN computers.

Ethernet 7 is my Ethernet connection that I've configured as a serving DHCP server, with shared internet from my Wifi interface. As described in these posts 1, 2, I was able to have internet and DHCP to the clients on the network by taking the following procedures:

Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network Connection.
On the WiFi interface, right-click and select Properties, then the Sharing tab.
Check the "Allow other network users…" box and pick the Home networking connection to share (e.g., Ethernet 7).



If this is the first time, you most likely be prompted details informing you that the shared interface will be assigned a static IP. Select Yes to continue


Now the connected device(s) have IP address in the subnet along with internet connection.
As stated both here and on the Wikipedia page, the service has the caveat that it is not configurable with regard to which addresses are utilized for the internal subnet. Hence why all connected devices are set to be in the subnet of 192.168.137.X on ICS from my Windows 10 system.
